# Files are uploading in wrong directory

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-3.0

I expect files (user avatar pictures) to be uploaded in `myproject/src/webapp/WEB-INF/upload/avatars`, but instead they are uploading in `C:/WEB-INF/upload/avatars`. Unfortunately i can't display these pictures located in C:/ directory to a jsp page. 
So, whats wrong with my code? Also is this practice considered ideal? Thanks

```
        String format = null;
        String fileName = null;
        String userName = userService.getLoggedInUsername();

        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

        // Get file extension
        fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        int index = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(index > 0){
            format = fileName.substring(index+1);
            format = format.toLowerCase();
        }

        // Creating the directory to store file
        String uploadPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload");

        File dir = new File(uploadPath);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        // Create the file on server
        String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + userName + "." + format;

        File serverFile = new File(filePath);
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.close();

        // Update photo path in db
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName(userName);
        user.setUserPhotoPath(filePath);
        userService.insertPhotoPath(user);
```

web.xml param:

```
<context-param> 
    <description>Location to store uploaded avatars</description> 
    <param-name>file-upload</param-name> 
    <param-value>
         /WEB-INF/upload/avatars
     </param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16859075/1811348

Answer (score 0):

You may need to map the path to your application using `ServletContext.getRealPath()` in order to get to the application's local folders.

This is because a web application runs under a virtual path on the web server.

See the [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)) documentation page for more info.